# Kubernetes stop containers from restarting automatically

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I recently upgraded Docker for Mac to v18.06 and noticed it can run a local k8s cluster. I was excited to try it out and ran one of our services via `kubectl apply -f deployments/staging/tom.yml`. The yml manifest does not have a restart policy specified. I then shut it down using `kubectl delete -f ...`. Since then, each time I start docker that container is starting automatically. Here is the output of `docker ps`, truncated for brevity

```
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED             NAMES
2794eae1f31e    b06778bfe205     "/bin/sh -c 'java -c…"   27 minutes ago      k8s_tom-joiner_tom-joiner-66fcfd84bc...
8dd19dd65486    b06778bfe205     "/bin/sh -c 'java -c…"   27 minutes ago      k8s_tom-loader_tom-loader-6cb9f7f4fb...
...
```

However, the image is not managed by Kubernetes, so I cannot do `kubectl delete -f`

```
kubectl get pods
No resources found.
```

How do I permanently shut down the image and prevent if from restarting automatically? I tried `docker update --restart=no $(docker ps -a -q)` with no luck

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you post the content of "deployments/staging/tom.yml". It's hard to say what is happening. Maybe containers are not running in default namespace.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This depends on your specific deployment, but [Kubernetes specifices that](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy)

> A PodSpec has a `restartPolicy` field with possible values `Always`, `OnFailure`, and `Never`. The default value is `Always`. [...]

So, if you don't want your pod to restart for any reason, you have to explicitly tell it not to. You don't provide the example contents of your YAML file so I cannot guess the best place to do that, but that's enough for general guidance I think.

---

Now, for the problem that you face: Docker is probably using a custom namespace. Use

```
kubectl get namespaces
```

to see what you get, then search for pods in those namespaces with

```
kubectl -n <namespace> get pods
```

Or if you're impatient just get it over with:

```
kubectl --all-namespaces get pods
```

Reference: [kubectl cheat sheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#viewing-finding-resources)

Comment: Thank you, that's it. The container was indeed running in a different namespace and `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` helped me figure that out. As soon as I knew that, it was a simple matter of `kubectl delete --all pods --namespace=whatever` to solve my problem

Comment: Kubernetes deployment only supports 'restartPolicy: Always' and does not support other values such as 'Never' or 'OnFailure.' The documentation is incorrect. For further information, see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24725